# MySQL filter for specific dates when dates just saved as UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, timestamp

I am using PHP to access a MySQL database. I have a table built up like this:

Table headers:

- id (INT, auto increment), profileid, timestamp

Table content:

- 1, 12345678, 1513814399 (= 12/21/2017)
- 2, 13451983, 1513814400 (= 12/21/2017)
- 3, 12345678, 1513944000 (= 12/22/2017)
- 4, 12345678, 1513944001 (= 12/22/2017)

The table shows which profileids have been called by a website visitor at which time.

So my question is now, how is it possible to show for example:
 "Give me the number of entries for profile no. 12345678 called on 12/22/2017", which would be "2" in this case.

I tried it with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(profileid), from_unixtime(timestamp, '%d') AS day, from_unixtime(timestamp, '%m') as month, from_unixtime(timestamp, '%Y') as year WHERE profileid='12345678' AND day=22 AND month=12 AND year=2017;
```

But it is not possible to access the columns "day", "month" and "year" because they to not exist in the table.

Can someone give me a tip how to do this? Another way would be to create three new columns (timestamp_day, timestamp_month and timestamp_year), but that's not a nice solution.

Thank you in advance!

teha

Comment: What data type does the "timestamp"-field have? Why not set it as "date" directly? Seems unnecessary to store it in a format that requires conversion to be used as you want it.

Comment: MySQL has date functions like `DAY()`, `MONTH()` and  `YEAR(), etc. which you can apply to your date-field. See: `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It has the type integer. Doing it like that because I am used to it to be honest and it's nice to calculate time differences.

Answer (score 5):

Just produce the date.  I think you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(profileid)
FROM t
WHERE DATE(from_unixtime(timestamp)) = '2017-12-22' AND
      profileid = '12345678';
```

I would be more inclined to write this as:

```
SELECT COUNT(profileid)
FROM t
WHERE profileid = '12345678' AND
      timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-22') AND
      timestamp < UNIX_TIMETAMP('2017-12-23');
```

This allows the query to make full use of an index on `t(profileid, timestamp)`.

Comment: This looks great. Didn't know it is possible like this. I will test it and give you feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQLs [DAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day), [MONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month), and [YEAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) functions combined with [FROM_UNIXTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

```
SELECT COUNT(profileid)
WHERE profileid='12345678'
AND DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))=22
AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))=12
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))=2017;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things here.

1. You can convert your raw timestamp to a MySQL `TIMESTAMP` object with `FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)`. You already know that.
2. Once you have a `TIMESTAMP` you can use all sorts of date functions on it.
3. You can convert the other direction with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`
4. When you're looking up records for one day you can do date range searching.

So your query should maybe be

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
     FROM t
    WHERE profileid = '12345678'
      AND timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-22')
      AND timestamp <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-23')
```

That will pick up every timestamp value on the day you want, up to but not including midnight on the next day.  If you have an index on `(profileid, timestamp)` this kind of query will be fast.

Note you can also do

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, profileid
     FROM t
    WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-22')
      AND timestamp <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-23')
    GROUP BY profileid
```

and get a result set showing the counts for all profile ids for that day. And, you can do

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, profileid, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) day
     FROM t
    WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-11-01')
      AND timestamp <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-01')
    GROUP BY profileid, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
```

and get everything for November.

You can do this

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, profileid, LAST_DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) month_ending
     FROM t
    WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01')
      AND timestamp <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01')
    GROUP BY profileid, LAST_DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
```

and get a month-by-month summary for a whole year.

Date arithmetic is useful. That's why many table designs use actual datestamp-like fields, like `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP`, rather than raw integer timestamps.